# change dataprovider to model given a relationship yii

Tags: yii

there are two tables, percentage and stores. There is a relationship, which I can get the data of percentage from stores, such as $stores->percentageTable.

I am looking to get the data from the percentage table. Ive been doing this through a loop but I don't want to use a loop anymore. Was hoping if there is a solution by using `CActiveDataProvider` instead.

view: I want something like the top part. The second part is what I normally would do.

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'commission',
//looking for a solution something like this
        'dataProvider'=> new CActiveDataProvider('Store',array('data'=>$commission)),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array( 
            'percent.commission_percent',
            'percent.date_from',
            'percent.date_to',
                ))); ?>
    <?php //I don't want this anymore...
    foreach($commission as $percent){
        echo $percent->com_percent;
        echo $percent->date_from;
        echo $percent->date_to;
    }
    ?>
```

Controller: I am loading based on the store and not the percentage table.

```
public function actionCommission($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);       
        $commission = $model->sellerCommissionOverrides;

        $this->render('commission',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'commission'=>$commission,
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define relation in model Store, i.e.

```
'percent'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'PercentageModel', 'store_id'),
```

then you will be able to use it like you want

```
    'dataProvider'=> new CActiveDataProvider('Store'),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array( 
        'percent.com_percent',
        'percent.date_from',
        'percent.date_to',
    ))); ?>
```

Comment: it's already defined,.. and that's actually the problem.. it's a one to many.. one store can have many rates

Comment: May be you can create CActiveDataProvider for PercentageModel? i don't think there is some other solution.

Comment: oh that's a bummer. Thanks.